# Tools to enable translation of A-Box ontology data

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

Does anyone know of any tools capable of defining a declarative mapping from T-Box structures from one ontology to another, which when executed can effect translation of A-Box instance data from one ontology's form to another's?

I have recently written such a tool to meet my needs, but I was wondering if I reinvented the wheel.

Comment: Is this a question or a statement? I suggest posting your tool, and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, it's a proprietary tool owned by my employer.  I was just wondering if anyone knew of competing solutions in the same space from which I could glean ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used SPARQL CONSTRUCT queries where I query on one model and construct new statements with properties from a different namespace.  I save these and then load them into the target model.  I have found this to be flexible but there are many places where I'd like to do additional processing on literals.

I have also wanted to use SWRL rules.

Comment: Thanks, these are good suggestions which are actually part of the solution we've come up with.  :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such tool that I know of.  Generally, you simply copy the tbox and abox definitions from one ontology to another, and write a transform tool.

I think this is the first ontology question I've seen on this site.  I hope more people use the tag.